# How to migrate database with sequel and mysql ?

Tags: ruby, sequel

I can migrate database without password like this

```
sequel -m db/migrations mysql://root@localhost/test
```

But how to pass a password ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
sequel -m db/migrations mysql://root:password@localhost/test
```

Comment: this should work: `sequel -m db/migrations mysql://root@localhost/test?password=foo@bar`